# How to compile all files to one exe?

Tags: c#, ilmerge

I wrote a project in C# that uses a lot of images, Milk models and openGL and i want to pack everything in one exe so i can upload it to my site.
Right now i got an exe that is depended on other files like jpgs etc'.
I've tried using ILMerge but couldn't get it to work. Is there a simpler solution?
thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create a setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add that as an embedded resource.

Inside Visual Studio :

1. Go to Solution Explorer,
2. Right click the image,
3. GO to Build Actions: Select Embedded Resource.

You will have that image inside the exe. Later you can use Reflection and get the image when you run your application.

========= Getting the Embedded image from the Application =========

First solve the first problem: by putting images as embedded resource.

Second problem: Access the images by using Reflection:

```
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EmbeddingExample.image1.bmp");
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(myStream);

    this.ClientSize = new Size(image.Width, image.Height);

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Image = image;
    pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(pb);
}
```

Borrowed Source Code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367(v=vs.71).aspx):

Comment: What do you mean by Reflection ? I've changed all my pics to Embedded and i can see that my exe is bigger in the debug folder but if i delete the pics from the debug folder and try to run the exe i get an error "this app must close.."

Comment: It's like the exe is still depended on the other files although it contains them.

Comment: Now that you have compiled your Images, you have your images inside the exe and the size of the exe will obviously increase. Since it provided you with the facility of putting your image inside the exe. 
Now you can take your exe everywhere you want and run your application anywhere without worrying about your images. 
The images are actually embedded inside the exe, where only the exe itself can access it. 

If you just want to upload images you can zip and upload it into your website, if its just for uploading stuff.

Comment: In this context, Reflection is a way to access images, texts, or anything that you build as an embedded resource. Reflection has a broad usage. One of the use is to access your images from the Exe itself.

Comment: That's my problem. The exe is bigger but wont run in another folder. It will only run in the folder with the pics

Comment: I'll try to explain my self better. Lets say my exe is 1 mb and a.jpg is 4 mb. Did the embedded thing and now my exe is 5 mb. The exe will only run inside a folder with a.jpg. If i'll delete a.jpg the exe will crash to a windows error "this app must close"

Comment: The files are inside the exe. How do i access them with reflection? i need to add the code above to mine?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367(v=vs.71).aspx might be helpful for you in that case..

Comment: I'm using something like this to load my pics. Trying to figure out how to use reflections from your link.  `void GenerateTextures()
        {
            GL.glGenTextures(5, Textures);
            string[] imagesName = { "L.jpg", "M.jpg", "RR.jpg", "R.jpg", "floor2.jpg" };
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {`

Comment: You should get the images from Reflection : Try something like : 
myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YOURASSEMBLYNAMESPACE.L.jpg");
also check the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Congratulations!! You did it. Now, please tick my answer as answer :) for all this effort of 2 hours :D

Answer (score 8):

You can put all your files/images into the exe as **Embedded Resources**.

See <s>[How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)</s> (This link currently 404s)

Comment: I don't have "Bitmap File" in the add new item menu. I have Txt file but no bitmap

Comment: You don't want to do "Add New Item", use "Add Existing item" since you already have the files.

Comment: I've changed all my pics to Embedded and i can see that my exe is bigger in the debug folder but if i delete the pics from the debug folder and try to run the exe i get an error "this app must close.." It's like the exe is still depended on the other files although it contains them

Comment: The how-to embed part of this answer has a link that returns HTTP 404 Not Found.

Comment: Looks like an issue on MSs end, because the VB and VC++ versions of the page still link to there. If I can find an updated link I will update this post.

Answer (score 3):

ilmerge is only for merging .net CLR binaries together, usually for bundling libraries into your main executable.

For things like art assets, you want to embed them as resources into your application. From a resource you can get a stream which lets you work with the data as if it were in a file.

See this MSDN article for information on embedding resources: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: The how-to embed part of this answer has a link that returns HTTP 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 2):

When you add an image to the project in properties you can set it as Embedded Resource, then it'll be added to the binary file (dll or exe)

Answer (score 1):

I shall prefer to create a satellite assembly for resource files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: This is an excellent alternative approach. Thank you for sharing.