# Is it possible to publish a visual studio c# project with ClickOnce, in just one .exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

Is it possible to publish a visual studio c# project with ClickOnce, in just one .exe?

I could not find a way to do it. My project has additional files it uses
like: it calls external exe, it links to dlls, etc. And all these files I want
to somehow embed in on .exe, rather than have an exe + additional files next to it.

Edit: the image explains even better what I need.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile all files to one exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862532/how-to-compile-all-files-to-one-exe)

Comment: that did not work because my project is vsto excel in c#, and additional files are created of which I have no control, and I can't set them as embedded resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add external dlls, resources, exe, and so on in your ClickOnce setup. Look at these photos. Sorry for the language.

[image]

[image]

If you want to publish it on IIS, you will need a host. Those files (application files,setup.exe and so on) will be stored in IIS. You only need to provide a 'publish.htm' or 'setup.exe' to users. 'publish.htm'/'setup.exe' will connect to your IIS. And if you use ClickOnce, your application will be updated more easily.

Otherwise, you just need VSInstaller in VS2010 or InstallShield Limited Edition in VS2012/2013. It will produce one .exe file.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the image in English please?

Comment: sorry,i don't have that language package. The first pic is Publish,and press ApplicationFolder.Then you can set the state of all files in your project .

Comment: Oh no :(, this is only present in Visual Studio 2013 right? I mean the Application Files button in the Publish options. Because it is not present in Visual Studio 2012 which is what I have.

Comment: No,mouserightclick your project, you will see `Publish`

Comment: Yes but then in Publish options for the project, the button "Application Files..." is not present. In Visual Studio 2013 I see it is above "Prerequisites" button.

Comment: By the way, using this approach, it still generates the "Application Files" folder. So, it seems I won't be able to have it all in one .exe.

Comment: oops,I have seen the button in vs2010,but I don't have 2012. Could you upload a pic?

Comment: oh, I know your demand now. You just need a setup package? In vs2010,you can use Visual Studio Installer.And you can use   installshield in vs2012/13.

Comment: Yes just one setup.exe, you can call it package I guess. InstallShield Limited Edition will do the job? By the way my project is vsto excel c#, does it matter? Can InstallShield still produce one exe only?

Comment: If you want to use clickonce,you could publish it on IIS. And then provide a publish.htm or setup.exe to user.

Comment: Nope, I need to be able to distribute the setup.exe file by email, USB, etc.

Comment: By publishing on IIS, do you mean I must own a web site?

Comment: Yes, InstallShield or vs intaller poduce just one exe. InstallShield Limited Edition is useful.

Comment: Can you please edit your original post with the last comment, and I will accept that as answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes,If you want to publish it on IIS,you need a host.Those files (application files,setup.exe and so on) will be stored in IIS.you only need to provide a publish.htm or setup.exe to users. publish.htm/setup.exe will connet to your IIS. And if you use clickonce,your application will be updated more easier.

Comment: I decided to go for InstallShield and have the freedom of distributing a single exe as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can add external exe in your installation. In your Setup and Deployment wizard Select the Application Folder and choose Add File then select your exe.

For prerequisites read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx) article.

Comment: What do you mean add external exe? By the way I edited my original post with an image that explains better my problem.