# How to put all the files used inside the winform application in the exe itself?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am making a winform application whereby I am using some images to show .It works fine when run . But what if I want to take the exe out from the debug folder and use it in some other machine then it will give exceptions that it can't find images on the same path(its obvious as it is not there in that machine path).
Idea to overcome this is to make a setup out of it,but that too is a tedious task.

Can it be possible that we can accomodate all the other sources(like images) used in the project in such a way that it should go along with the exe ?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862532/how-to-compile-all-files-to-one-exe

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of an odd error, because the `*.exe` file in the `Debug` folder is created after adding all the resources into it. And that's why the `*.exe` file gets lager in size. But it will be a problem if you have mentioned the paths of the resources (like images) manually.
To avoid that always use the properties panel to import resources to the project and this will create the `Resoures.resx` automatically. Then all the resources will stick to the `*.exe` file.

> But if you have mentioned the paths manually you must provide them in the targeted computer which you are going to use the `*.exe` file. To make it more easier, give a path in the same folder where the `*.exe` file exist.
>
> For example give simple paths like `(@"image.jpg")`, without giving paths like `("C:\Users\Sam\Pictures\image.jpg")`.
>   And create a setup including all the resources like images, databases, etc.

[image: Properties panel]

[image: Import]

Comment: I tried with the link given by Todd and it worked smoothly.
Thanks.